# Unexpected end of JSON input getting Instagram JSON data with request

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, instagram-api

I'm trying to display the JSON data form instagram's URL: https://www.instagram.com/apple/?__a=1.

If I put this in browser, it shows the JSON, but I want to be able to get it with express so I can attempt to capture any data I need to with that URL

```
const express = require("express");
const Instagram = require("node-instagram").default;
const keys = require("./config/keys");
const app = express();
const request = require("request");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  const url = "https://www.instagram.com/apple/?__a=1";
  request(url, (err, response, body) => {
    const json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json); 
    res.json(request.json);
  });
});

app.listen(5000);
```

When I'm trying to deploy this in localhost, I'm getting an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are logged in to instagram in your browser, you are getting authentication via cookies, and everything works fine, but if you are not logged in, the url https://www.instagram.com/apple/?__a=1 responds wit a 403 (access denied) error. This is the case for your back-end code since you are not sending cookies or authentication headers.

You are probably getting an error but not checking for errors in your request callback (the `err` parameter).

According to the [instagram developer documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/), you need to register your app and authenticate before you can perform the request with OAuth credentials.

Check [request's documentation on OAuth signing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#oauth-signing) for more info.